# How do you restore previously tracked footage?

Tags: camera, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I've recently reformatted my PC, and once I reinstalled and loaded my Blender file back up, the trackers were still there, but the footage wasn't. I tried to reload the sequence back up, but now that the footage is there, the trackers aren't. Though they do appear in the camera's view in Object Mode. How do I go about reasigning those trackers to the footage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Movie Clip Editor use the **footage settings**.
Click on the folder icon and navigate to the place where the video clip is stored.
[image]

Alternatively you can use the outliner. Set it to  Data-block and manually edit the path to the Movie CLip file.

[image]