# Trackers in re-linked footage don't match the features on video

Tags: camera, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I've managed to [get my footage re-linked to my project again](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131922/how-do-you-restore-previously-tracked-footage) after reformatting my PC, but I've noticed that all of my trackers keep moving around. Is there any way to fix this, or have I got to delete them all and start again? :-\ I'd rather not re-do them; tracking is not my favourite aspect of Blender.

Thanks

Save file:

[image]

Footage:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/09bq3u1tqzbkmic/Real_Footage.mov?dl=0

Comment: How can something like this be avoided? If I, or anyone, were to reformat their PC and reloaded their project up, the video footage won't load, the user will have to point Blender to the video, but they'll find their trackers aren't working correctly anymore. They just sway all over the place.

Comment: Is is linked to the exact same video file?

Comment: It is, yeah. I would've asked in the same thread...

Comment: Sorry, of course. I'll add it to the original post. Thanks.
EDIT: It looks like the link to upload files is broken. :-\

Comment: Nah, I don't think that's it. The page to upload files just wasn't loading up. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The trackers on the linked footage do not match with any trackable features in the video.

[image]

it looks like you are using some frame offset (the 1st frame in the composition and the 1st frame of the video file are not the same) 
Somehow the offset information got lost in the re-link or at some point it changed in the file (my guessing powers are quite limited).
You might need to find the correct start frame manually by sliding the Offset (place the cursor over the Offset box, right click with the mouse and drag to visually find the point where your trackers and the image match correctly)
If you offset the image by 500 frames things line up better.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... That seems to have helped somewhat. I've noticed some still move around slightly though.

Comment: find the correct offset. I just made a wild guess. Only you know how this was set up  originally.